# Create a file for upload in rails 3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My web app allows users to record their geolocation data. I need to somehow get that geolocation data into a file so I can put it in s3 storage. I have no idea how to go about this, but the controller already has file uploads to s3 set up using paperclip.

Is there some way to generate a file with javascript and then attach that file when the user clicks save? The other option I was thinking is that I could add a bunch of strings to the body using jQuery .data() method, but then I don't know how to attach a string as a file in my rails 3 form.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try out Amazon's simple db instead of s3 for this?  It would be more appropriate than creating files to store data in s3.

Amazon recently released a ruby sdk for their web services, SDB included:
https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby

Edit: Or better yet, forget using SDB directly.  I had forgotten that that SDK includes an implementation of ActiveModel called AWS::Record.  Should make this trivial.

I'm assuming you're on Heroku or something and don't have a method of data persistence?

edit: looking quickly at paperclip's assign method, there's a chance this would work.

```
yourmodel.your_paperclip_attachment = StringIO.new(params[:your_posted_geolocation_data])
```

Paperclip appears to handle creating a tempfile from the stream.

Comment: Correct, this is on heroku. After looking through the sdk, I found there is a 1000 byte limit for objects and 10gb limit for a domain. Based on this, I believe I need to continue to use S3 for storage. The 'file' I want to save could be any where from 72kb to 10mb.

Comment: yikes 10mb?  Your app could POST the data and you could create a temp file server side and save it as your paperclip attachment, I suppose.  You're not going to create a file with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'POST the data', but I did come up with a funky work around. I add the data to a hidden text area, and when the form is submitted to the controller I use that nifty StringIO.new(). It works, though is a little hacky.

Comment: Cool, that's all I meant.  POST as in send the data to the server in a POST request, through a form most likely, which is what you did.  Glad it worked.